# Properties of topological spaces with respect to subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $B \subset A \subset X$ where $X$ is a topological space.

prove that if $B$ is closed in $X$, then $B$ is closed with respect to the subspace topology on $A$.

I'm guessing, since $B$ is closed in $(X,\mathcal T)$ then $B$ is closed in $\mathcal T _A$ since $\mathcal T_A \subset (X,\mathcal T)$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Maybe you should quote the subspace topology. Because if $A$ isn't open or closed, then $\mathcal{T}_A\nsubseteq \mathcal{T}$.

Comment: Do you mean, Explicitly state in the problem if A is open, closed (or something else), correct?

Comment: Yes. The subspace topology is not necessarily  a sub-collection of the original topology. It is true however if $A$ is open. But you've already been given  a comprehensive answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is just this: since $B$ is closed in $X$, $B^\complement$ is open in $X$. But the complement of $B$ in $A$ is $B^\complement\cap A$. Since $B^\complement$ is open in $X$, $B^\complement\cap A$ is open in $A$. In other words, $B$ is closed in $A$.

Comment: thanks, also, is it safe to assume that if B is open, then it would be open in the subspace topology of A by a similar line of reasoning?

Comment: It is actually simpler.  Since $\mathcal{T}_A=\{O\cap A\,|\,O\in\mathcal T\}$, it follows immediately that if $B\in\mathcal T$ and $B\subset A$, then $B\in\mathcal{T}_A$ (just take $O=B$).

Answer (score 1):

For $B$ to be closed in $A$, then there must be a closed set $V$ in the topology of $X$ such that $B=A\cap V$. If $B$ is closed in $X$, you can let $V=B$.